# How can you make Pylons email you the full post parameters with an error report?

Tags: python, post, pylons

Pylons can email you errors when something goes wrong in production mode, but it truncates the post parameters so it's hard to see what the error is. Is there a way to make it email you the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make Pylons email you errors in development, testing, and production modes, just so long as you put the correct email information in the .ini file.

The facilities for emailing you error messages come from the WebError middleware, particularly the [weberror.reporter](http://bitbucket.org/bbangert/weberror/src/tip/weberror/reporter.py) module.  The only truncating that occurs there is in the subject line of the email.  It is possible that the error is being truncated before it gets to WebError.  You may want to, on a test deployment, tweak the WebError middleware of your Pylons project to double-check what it's accepting in and sending out.

Can you give an example of such a truncated error message email?  Do you mean that it truncates the HTTP POST data of a request that caused an error?

Comment: The original poster has not replied but I have the same problem. You can see an example of the truncated `webob._parsed_post_vars` here: http://pastebin.com/32mrw9Cy